# ODBC error connecting to MySQL

Tags: 14.04, server, 64-bit, mysql

I wonder if someone could help with an issue I can't seem resolve with ODBC for MySQL.  I am reasonably new to Linux, so any assistance that can be offered would be helpful.

If it helps, I am running Ubuntu 14.04 x64 on two VirtualBox machines.

I've installed MySQL server on a machine that appears to be working as I can create databases, tables, insert and remove data and run queries without any issue.  I've create a database called `my_db` and a user called `db_root` within MySQL.

I am now trying to connect to this MySQL server from another machine but I don't seem to be able to get the ODBC connection working.  I've looked at a number of online instructions, but they pretty much all give the same set of instructions.

Started off by install `unixODBC`, `unixODBC-dev` and `libmyodbc`.  Then edited the `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file.  Mine looks like:-

```
[MySQL]
Description = ODBC for MySQL
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage = 1
```

Then edit the `/etc/odbc.ini` file.  Mine looks like:-

```
[mysql-connector]
Driver       = MySQL
Description  = ODBC for MySQL
Server       = 192.168.1.1
Port         = 3306
User         = db_root
Password     = password
Database     = my_db
Option       = 3
Socket       =
```

This is where some instructions change.  Some say that there should be a file called `mysql.sock` or `mysqld.sock` in the directory `/var/lib/mysql` and this file should be set as the path for the `SOCKET` in the `odbc.ini` file. I have no `mysql` directory inside `/var/lib` and searching my machine for `mysql.sock` and `mysqld.sock` turns up blank.  Some instructions do include the *`SOCKET`* field in the `odbc.ini` file.

All the instructions then say, test your connection with the command something like `echo "select 1" | isql -v mysql-connector`.  I always get the same error of `[S1000][unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.1' (111)`.

I've been searching for days, but can't seem to find anything that might point me in the right direction to resolving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more searching, I found the answer was the MySQL setup.  In the **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**, MySQL was only listening on port 3306 for local traffic.  This was fixed by removing the line **bind-address = 127.0.0.1** in the **my.cnf** file.